# How do I combine 2 prewritten Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function

Would I want to nest one function into another?

Comment: Combine in what way? Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context. Functions typically represent a single piece of logic and it would therefore go against this technique of abstraction to combine two functions just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're asking?

```
function add1(x){
  return x + 1;
}

function mult2(x){
    return x * 2;
}

function add1ThenMult2(x){
  return mult2(add1(x));
}

add1ThenMult2(10); // --> 22
```

or, hiding the 2 functions ...

```
  var add1ThenMult2 = (function(){

    function add1(x){
      return x + 1;
    }

    function mult2(x){
      return x * 2;
    }

    function add1ThenMult2(x){
      return mult2(add1(x));
    }

    return add1ThenMult2;

  }());

  add1ThenMult2(10); // --> 22
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [jquery-aop](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/) for adding advice around or before a given function.

Or [prototype's `wrap` function](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/wrap/).